# Trouble with Curl

Tags: php, curl

Hi i am trying to use the [pushbots](https://pushbots.com/) [api](https://pushbots.com/developer/api/1#getAnalytics) to get the analytics of my app. The problem is i dont understand curl very well or how to implement it.

I hope someone can explain me how to use the code i pasted below.

```
curl -X GET \
-H "x-pushbots-appid: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" \
-H "x-pushbots-secret: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
https://api.pushbots.com/analytics
```

**EDIT:**
I am now using the code

```
<?php
$headers = array("Content-Type: application/json","x-pushbots-appid: XXXXXXXXXXXXXX","x-pushbots-secret: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");

$appid = "x-pushbots-appid: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
$secretid = "x-pushbots-secret: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"api.pushbots.com/analytics");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $appid&$secretid);


curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
//set the headers now
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
$output = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close ($ch);

var_dump($output);


?>
```

And i am getting this error now:

```
string(64) "{"code":"MethodNotAllowedError","message":"POST is not allowed"}"
```

Comment: Alright,from what i can understand from the question you want an explanation about your code and how you can use it. Stackoverflow isnt the place i think for this question. Check out Code Review, like the name says its a code review site and maybe the people using that site can explain it in depth.

Comment: HI @CollinKoornstra I appreciate you're trying to be helpful, but this question is completely Off-Topic for Code Review. The golden rule of CR is that code must already be working as intended. Explaining/fixing code is not what we do (It is **precisely** what SO is for). You might want to read [A Guide to CR for Stack Overflow Users](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1). Send a `GET` request using `cURL` to :- https://api.pushbots.com/analytics

2). Data fields which you need to send are `x-pushbots-appid` and `x-pushbots-secret`.

3). The headers should be `Content-Type: application/json`.

Here's a quick example.

```
<?php
$headers = "Content-Type: application/json";
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://api.pushbots.com/analytics");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET"); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
            "x-pushbots-appid=somevalue&x-pushbots-secret=somevalue");


curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
//set the headers now
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
$output = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close ($ch);

var_dump($output);
?>
```

Comment: Could you maybe give me an example of this?

Comment: @AmandoVledder
I've updated my answer and included a quick solution.

Comment: It's just a sample code. Modify it according to your needs.

Comment: ive edited my post, its giving me an error now. Could you help me with that?