# How to create cURL Requests with PHP

Tags: php, curl, shellcheck

So I found this code:

```
data=$(curl \
  --silent \
  --user-agent "ShellCheck@github.com/lollek/scripts-and-stuff" \
  --data-urlencode "script@$file" \
  "http://www.shellcheck.net/shellcheck.php")
```

Here is full code:
https://github.com/lollek/scripts-and-stuff/blob/master/bin/shellcheck

Is it possible to make the same request using php, and if yes, how can I do it? I mean just sending my code ($file) to shellcheck.net/shellcheck.php and get request from it. So, somebody have any idea?

@edit

I found something like this:

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => 'http://www.shellcheck.net/shellcheck.php'
));
$resp = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

But how can I send here my $file?

@edit2

Now I'm trying something like this:

```
<?php
   if( $_REQUEST["code"])
   {
    echo "Your code: ". $_REQUEST['code']. "<br />";      
    $data = $_REQUEST['code'];
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.shellcheck.net/shellcheck.php"); 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data); 
    $resp = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    exit();
   }
?>
<html>
   <body>

      <form action="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>" method="POST">
         Code: <input type="text" name="code" />
         <input type="submit" />
      </form>

   </body>
</html>
```

But still nothing :/

Comment: Yes, it's possible. No, we're not going to do it for you. We're not a code translation service.

Comment: Your answer was so helpful...

Comment: Well, I think @MarcB 's answer is correct

Comment: You probably wan't to send the contents of the $file not the $file itself.
In php one of the ways of reading file into variable, e.g.:
$fileContent = file_get_contents($file); //$file of course is path to actual file

Comment: Yes, I want to send contents of the file or form :P But I still have no idea how can I add this contest to curl array.

Comment: Have you checked [cURL library documentation](http://php.net/curl) first?

Comment: Yes, I tried some code from documentation but still didn't work :/

Comment: You can take some reference from my answer here. http://stackoverflow.com/a/33680312/5073447

Comment: what is the input of the bash file? is the url of the file? or what?

Comment: I just input in form some wrong bash code to get answer for shellcheck, for example [code]test= "test"[/code].

Comment: You can also just install the command-line version of [ShellCheck](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck) and call it via `exec()`.